# Solving trigonometric equations without using calculator

Tags: trigonometry, pi

How to solve the following trigonmetric equations without using calculator?

1)$\pi +\arccos{(x)}=\cot{(\arcsin{(x)})}=\frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{x}$

2)$\theta-\tan{(\theta)}=2\pi$

Answers: Using hp 50g graphing calculator, i got answer to the first question as **0.217233628212**

Using hp 50g graphing calculator, I got answer answer to second question **1.78977584927 and -1.44206652976**

Comment: What have you tried without a calculator? See [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959).

Comment: @Dhamnekar Vinod: Your calculator uses numerical iteration methods. No other way to solve transcendental equations.